# Maximum Date of record with LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm new to LINQ and struggling to to get records with the latest publishing_Date

The Table has `Settlement_date`, `Settlement_Period`, `Publishing_Date` and `Indicated_Value`

The table as multiple records for the same `settlement_date` and `Settlement_Period` for different `publishing_date`'s

the data i'm after is `settlement_date`, `Settlement_Period`, `Indicated_Value` for the latest `publishing_date` in each period

`Settlement_period` is between `1` and `48`

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? Do you have a minimum example that people can use to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Sorry missed that I'm using VB.net

Comment: I can get the max date with the group by code but can't get the value                                                                                                           dim Query1 =from Q in sys_indDEMs
where Q.settlement_date = "2016-03-20" _
order by Q.settlement_period
group  Q by q.settlement_period into g = group Select settlement_period, maxdate = g.Max(Function(Q) q.publishing_Date) 
order by settlement_period

Answer (score 0):

First, you actually need to get the latest publishing date:

```
var latestPublishingDate = collection.Max(x => x.Publishing_Date);
```

Then, to get all records with just that publishing date:

```
var result = collection.Where(x => x.Publishing_Date == latestPublishingDate);
```

While it may be tempting to nest the calls, that would recalculate the max for every record.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to group data by using [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531412.aspx) clause.

```
Dim result = dataContext _
    .GroupBy(Function(x) New With {.SD = settlement_date, .SP = Settlement_Period}) _
    .Select(Function(grp) New With{ _
        .SettltementDate = grp.SD, _
        .SettlementPeriod = grp.SP, _
        .MaxPublishingDate = grp.Max(Function(d) d.publishing_date)})
```

Finally i'd suggest to read this:
[LINQ - Sample Queries (101 samples)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Sample-Queries-13a42a54)
[LINQ 101 Samples - Lambda Style](http://linq101.nilzorblog.com/linq101-lambda.php)